# Excel 2010 Userform: Date entered in Textbox 3 will automatically record day of the week in Textbox 7 (i.e. Mon)

Tags: excel, excel-2010, userform, vba

I have a userform and I need for the user to enter the date in textbox 3 which will then specify the actual day of the week (abbreviated ddd) in textbox 7.  Example 12/7/2014 in Textbox3 will result in "Sun" in textbox 7.

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Have you tried putting `Me.TextBox7 = Format(Me.TextBox3, "ddd")` in the `Textbox3_Change()` event?

Comment: Thank you, I tried this but it didn't work for my project.  Of course, I may have entered something wrong.  Appreciate your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a few different components for that.  Also, note that I used TextBox1 and TextBox2 for this example, for the sake of future readers.  Please apply your own textbox names where they apply.

- You will need an event handler to run the code after the value is input.  "_AfterUpdate"
- Make sure the textbox has text in it. Ideally, you'd want to make sure it's a date format as well.  For the sake of this example, I'm just checking to see if the Textbox is empty.
- Convert the text they input to a Date.  CDate(text)
- Format to "ddd"
- Return the value back into TextBox2

**TESTED:**

```
Private Sub TextBox1_AfterUpdate()

Dim tDate As Date

    If TextBox1.Text <> "" Then
        tDate = CDate(TextBox1.Text)
        TextBox2.Text = Format(tDate, "ddd")
    End If

End Sub
```

[image: Result]

**To summarize the functions listed:**

```
TextBox1_AfterUpdate   'Handles the event that when the user is done updating, code runs.  As 
                       'opposed to _Change, where it runs as soon as you type at all.

CDate(text)   

Format(tdate, "ddd")
```

**A few other options:**

```
Weekday(date, firstDayOfWeek (Optional))   ' There are other options for this as well

WorksheetFunction.Text(text, format)       'This worksheet function has many uses.  See link.
```

**Links:**

[Format Function](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/format_date.php)

[Weekday Function](https://support.office.com/client/Weekday-Function-05d360d7-2c3f-4691-9448-c96ea0351940)

[TEXT Function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/text-function-HP010342952.aspx)

edit:  added links - updated answer

Comment: Do you know if there's a benefit to using `WorksheetFunction.Text` over `Format( , "ddd")`?

Comment: PJ Thank you so very much.  This works perfectly.  I literally spent days searching and trying various codes...  I am new to VBA and appreciate the advice, instructions, and sharing of knowledge and experience.